# How to Make Page Text Go From Right to Left?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, text-direction

I am trying to change a template direction from ltr into rtl. I added dir="rtl" code to  and the divs but nothing changes
I also tried to do it in css by adding `direction: rtl;` to body class and other classes but still not working!

```
{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

and finally tried js code but also doesn't work

```
var children = document.children;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   children[i].style.direction = "rtl";
}
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`direction: rtl;` should work.

Snippet:

```html
<div style="direction: rtl;">
    hi
</div>
```